# SaaS Maturity Level depending on number of Tenants (Nodes)

Tags: web, architecture, saas, maturity

I am working on a mid-size web application, that my client is planning to convert to a Software as a Service (SaaS) model, and sell to Customers. I [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479069.aspx) up on SaaS and have so far understood that there are 4 Maturity levels

[image]

My client wants an architecture similar to Maturity Level 2 (Configurable, with One to One relationship between Tenants and Instances). I also think that my present architecture aligns itself pretty well with this idea, though I will need to work a lot for making it configurable.

My question is regarding the number of tenants vs Maturity Level relationship. Up to how many tenants is this maturity level viable? I don't know yet what my client's customer base is going to be, so in my proposal, I want to suggest something like -

- Maturity Level A for XX-YY (0-50 for instance) tenants
- Maturity Level B for YY-ZZ (50-500) tenants

Is there a popular consensus on the number of tenants ideal for each Maturity Level? If no, how can I analyze my application and make the appropriate decision for my app?

TIA!